# Azure static web app generated envs and azure AD tenant reply urls

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-static-web-app

We have an azure static web app with authentication provided by azure active directory (company tenant)

This works for production but when we open a PR and get a staging url generated it appends an identifier e.g. https://salmon-mountain-xxxxxxx-20.azurestaticapps.net

Obviously this isn't set as a reply/redirect url in the app registration so auth fails.

The site is currently on the public internet but only organisation AD accounts can log in. Is my only option adding a wildcard in the manifest? I know wildcards aren't generally recommended and this functionality may vanish in the future

Answer (score -1):

•   You have the option of adding a user to a role, generate invitations to associate specific users to a specific role through the azure portal by adding a comma separated list of the role names to be assigned. These can be defined in staticwebapp.config.json.file and this file can be located in ‘app_location’ in the workflow file of the app build.

•   Once the external users for whom the app to be accessed are invited, you now must check the route rules for any change in the authentication process. Routes are secured by adding one or more role names into a rule's allowedRoles array. By default, every user belongs to the built-in anonymous role, and all logged-in users are members of the authenticated role. Optionally, users are associated to custom roles via invitations. For instance, to restrict a route to only authenticated users, add the built-in authenticated role to the allowedRoles array as below: -

```
{
   "route": "/profile",
    "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
 }
```

•   Also, check the response overrides that are configured for your static web app. They should be as follows: -

```
  {
   "responseOverrides": {
    "400": {
       "rewrite": "/invalid-invitation-error.html"
    },
     "401": {
       "statusCode": 302,
       "redirect": "/login"
     },
      "403": {
        "rewrite": "/custom-forbidden-page.html"
       },
       "404": {
        "rewrite": "/custom-404.html"
       }
      }
     }
```

•   Also, check the networking section to control the network configuration of your static web app. It has details of all the IP addresses that are allowed to access your app.

Please check the below link for more information on configuring the app files of your static web app for options on configuring other than wildcard details in the app manifest file: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization

Comment: Hi - just to clarify, the production version of the app works perfectly fine with AD auth. I'm trying to figure out how to have auth work with staging URLS without having to use wildcard reply URI's

Thanks

Comment: You can try including the following authentication link in the code snippet to forward the staging url request for authentication: - ' <a href="/.auth/login/github">Login</a> ' while for AAD, you can use ' <a href="/.auth/login/aad">Login</a> '

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue - I know how to add / enable AD login. My issue is when a static web app generates a staging environment the login doesn't work unless you manually add the unique staging URL to the reply url list